# How to generate DDL for a table-column in any database using java?

Tags: java, database, comparison

My requirement is I want to diff two database which can be any database ,for now considering 3 database Oracle,MySQL,PostGresql and suppose if any of two database has a common schema with common table name,but lets say those two tables are different. The tables can have different column or different column data type etc.How can I generate a diff query which on can be executed on a particular DB to make both of them equal. I was going through schemacrawler(http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/how-to.html) but didint got any API which can be used to generated DDL. Though the tool is good to crawl through schema and table -columns etc,but how can I generate DDL in java so that I can make both database equal. I can get database meta data using java api but how can I use it to generate appropriate DDL to make both database equal,if possible please paste sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use tool called [DBSolo](http://www.dbsolo.com/) to compare schema and generate diff sql. It is invoked via scripts, not using java code though.

I used [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/diff) in my personal work. The example given are in script, it will be trivial to integrate using java.